# CreateItemFromTemplate Type mismatch

Tags: vba, email, templates, outlook, mailitem

I have code to generate an email based on data on a userform.

It worked for a long time across multiple machines, but when I changed machines it started throwing a run-time error 13 type mismatch on on the `CreateItemFromTemplate` method in the following section:

```vb
Private Sub AcaoEnviar_Click()
    Dim OutlookApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim EmailKRI As Outlook.MailItem

    Set EmailKRI = OutlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE)
```

The code still runs on other machines, suggesting the problem is local. My Outlook library is the same as on the other machines, and the only difference I´m aware of is that I´m running it on a 64-bit system and 32-bit office, while most others have 32-bit systems (one other has the same 64-bit setup and runs fine).

Changing the object declaration from Outlook.MailItem to Object seems to solve the problem, which I think eliminates problems with Outlook's programmatic access, and in any case, my Antivirus status is valid.

I'm still confused as to why such an error would occur only with me.
Is there any solution so that I can go back to early binding for that email object?

Answer (score 1):

You will get that error if CreateItemFromTemplate returns something other than MailItem object. Are you sure the OFT file is for a regular mail item.
As a test, declare EmailKRI  as a generic Obejct and at run time check the value of the EmailKRI.Class property. It is supposed to be 43 (OlObjectClass.olMail) for the regular MailItem objects.

Comment: Yes, I had done that test, and EmailKRI returns type Object/MailItem, .class is olMail.

Comment: I can only suggest there is a problem with the Outlook type library at run-time...